# Can I display the "Refers to" portion of a named range as text?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, named-ranges

I am an educator writing an exam on basic excel usage.  I ask students to set print area.  I would like to have a single cell that displays the cell range they have selected as their print area.

Print area is stored in a named range called "Print_Area".  I would like to display the "refers to" portion of that named range as text.  I am using the function "FormulaText" to display the contents of specific cells for other questions, but when I attempt to use FormulaText on a named range, I get an array of cells as output with #REF! in every cell.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I've tried using indirect, looked at Match (it only works with one dimensional arrays), FormulaText (as mentioned above), and tried googling a wide variety of terms.  Nothing I've tried has come even close.  There is some mention of ability to reference things with VB, but I'm not familiar enough to understand what's going on with VB, and would prefer not to have to learn it to write my own code for this problem.  But that's my fallback if I can't find a non-VB solution, or someone willing to write a VB solution that I could insert.

Comment: I was able to do it with a combination of the `Print_Area`, `Cell`, `Offset`, `Columns`, `Rows`, and contatenating them.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  In my example, Print_Area refers to =Sheet1!$F$9:$J$17,Sheet1!$F$18:$P$26  What would the formula look like?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
=CELL("address",Print_Area) & ":" & ADDRESS(ROWS(Print_Area),COLUMNS(Print_Area),1,1)
```

It will give you the Print Area for the particular worksheet.

Adding the sheet reference will give you the value for any other given sheet's Print Area. So for Sheet13, the above would be:

```
=CELL("address",Sheet13!Print_Area)  &  ":"  &  ADDRESS(ROWS(Sheet13!Print_Area),COLUMNS(Sheet13!Print_Area),1,1)
```

Your Print Area includes two ranges which give this fits. I do not, at the moment see a "natural" solution, as above, for resolving that. However, you could make each portion of the Print Area a discrete Named Range and use the above on each portion.

The difficulty there continues to be extracting the discrete portions from the Name Manager's "Print_Area" name for the sheet. If I could do that, it could be fed into the above formulas instead of making each discrete portion a Named Range. So, it would rely upon physical (non-formula) work.

Not a problem if the Print Area need not have additional discrete areas added or removed "on the fly." As long as any changes are design changes, not user preference or dynamic, it would work fine, but the moment they change outside of your control, the hands-on work would be needed.